# 100% disk full on Centos?

Tags: centos, disk-space

Situation on machine:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        14G  3.9G     0 100% /
devtmpfs         59G     0   59G   0% /dev
tmpfs            59G  932M   59G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs            59G  2.5G   57G   5% /run
tmpfs            59G     0   59G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        14G  3.9G     0 100% /home
/dev/sda1      1014M  181M  834M  18% /boot
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /run/user/0
```

Can someone tell me, why is this 100% used on the `/`?

`inodes---` is ok.

Comment: is `/` btrfs, and are you taking snapshots periodically?

Comment: How on earth can we tell you why? You can start by running even the simplest diagnostic - `du -xs /*`.

Comment: @FrankThomas the / is btrfs and there is no planning for taking snapshots, when  I  truncate the log files , the issue goes away, but it happen again. I appreciate your time.

Comment: do you run `btrfs balance` regularly?

Comment: no I do not run btfrs balance regularly